# google maps show multiple location (Error: locations[i] is undefined)

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, while-loop

I am trying to show multiple users location using Google Map API, I have to show all value from master_service_provider table for this I am using while loop.

But I am getting JavaScript error **Type Error: locations[i] is undefined**.

```
 <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          var map;
          function initMap() {
            var i = '0';
    <?php
    $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM `master_service_provider`");

       $a=0;
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $service_provider_id = $row['id'];
              $fullname = $row['fullname'];
           $fulladdress = $row['fulladdress'];
                 $phone = $row['phone'];
                   $lat = $row['lat'];
                   $lng = $row['lng'];

    ?>
     var <?php echo 's'.$phone; ?> = {
               info: '<h3><?php echo $fullname; ?></h3>\
                      <h4><?php echo $fulladdress; ?></h4>\
                      <a href="view_service_provider.php?service_provider_id=<?php echo $service_provider_id; ?>">View Info</a>',
                      lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>,
                      long: <?php echo $lng; ?>
      };


      var locations = [
          [<?php echo 's'.$phone; ?>.info, <?php echo 's'.$phone; ?>.lat, <?php echo 's'.$phone; ?>.long, <?php echo $a++; ?>],
        ];

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));

        i++;


     <?php } ?>

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.198313, 72.893533),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

      var marker;


    }

        </script>
```

Comment: I would suggest simplifying it. You have a mix of php and javascript. Can you dump out the json you are expecting to get back/build up using your php and then create a javascript object/array to debug your javascript without the added confusion of your php?

Comment: Like Max said.  Separate the php from the javascript.  Keep php on top.  Don't interrupt javascript functions by php data.  What you should do, is generate "var locations", then look at the page source, see if it looks like a javascript array (notice: it doesn't.  Why does it contain $phone ? why [1] and [2]? that's not where lat and lng are... lat and lng are in $lat and $lng ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this, I think.

Fill the ... parts yourself, but keep the general structure of the code.

Let me know if you get it to work

```
<?php
...
// do this on top, not in the middle of javascript
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, lat, lng, fullname, fulladdress, phone FROM master_service_provider");  // don't use *, specify the columns you want

$mydata = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // use _assoc rather than _array
  $mydata[] = $row ;   // push current row to the data object
}
// now we translate this php array to a javascript array of objects.
// it should resemble something like:
// var locations = [ {"id": "1", "lat":"4.51", "lng":"50.53", "fullname":"John Smith", ... }, {"id": "2", lat":"5.14", ...} ] ;
// use json_encode() to realize this

echo '<script>var locations = '. json_encode($mydata) .' ;</script>';
?>

<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {

    ...
   for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['lng']),
      title: locations[i]['fullname'],
      map: map
    });

    ...

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
      return function () {
        infowindow.setContent('phone: ' + locations[i]['phone']);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
   }
   ...

  }
</script>
```

Comment: you defiantly need a loop in there to fix the `i` issue